# Does Samsung have a tool similar to Rescue and Smart Assistant Tool of Motorola?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, motorola

My Motorola smartphone would not boot after an update and then I used [Rescue and Smart
Assistant Tool](https://www.motorola.com/us/rescue-and-smart-assistant/p) of Motorola to reinstall a new Android OS on my phone. Now, I am considering to buy a Samsung Galaxy smartphone and I am wondering if Samsung has a similar tool so that in case of an update failure I can easily restore the device.

Comment: I guess [Odin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin_(firmware_flashing_software))/Heimdall is the comparison. Not sure how easy to use it since I never had Samsung phones.

Comment: Odin can bring back device to factory state, but there exist no tool to recover userdata